# Java How can ArrayList<String> be sorted/ordered by index?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

So i have this ArrayList:

```
list.get(0) == "love"  
list.get(1) == "foo"  
list.get(2) == "make"  
list.get(3) == "links"
```

What i want is:

```
list.get(0) == "links"  
list.get(1) == "make"  
list.get(2) == "foo"  
list.get(3) == "love"
```

I have tried this but not working:

```
public static void orderDescending(final ArrayList<String> list){
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            Integer i1 = list.indexOf(s1);
            Integer i2 = list.indexOf(s2);
            return i1.compareTo(i2);
        }
    });
 }
```

Comment: what you're showing here is not sorting, but reversing... did you want to reverse the list?

Comment: yes i want to reverse it. Sorry.

Comment: If your intention is to reverse the elements then use this Collections.reverse(list).

Comment: yeah, i agree with @Hristo. What you want is reversing the arraylist.

Comment: Although I have to say, I respect the audacity of sorting with a comparator based on the index of the item in the list.

Comment: Yes this is the deal, thanx a lot for all and vive stackoverflow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Collections.reverse(list);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply,

```
Collections.reverse(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple list reversal algorithm. If you don't care about the algorithm, use [Collections.reverse()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse%28java.util.List%29).

```
public static void reverse(List<String> list) {

    if (list == null) {
        return;
    }

    int size = list.size();
    int mid = list.size() / 2;

    ListIterator<String> fwd = list.listIterator();
    ListIterator<String> rev = list.listIterator(size);

    for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++) {
        String tmp = fwd.next();
        fwd.set(rev.previous());
        rev.set(tmp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did a small mistake otherwise you have almost done it.

You should have tried "return **i2**.compareTo(**i1**);"

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Reverse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("love");
        list.add("foo");
        list.add("make");
        list.add("links");
        System.out.println(list);
        orderDescending(list);
        System.out.println(list);
    }

    public static void orderDescending(final ArrayList<String> list) {
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
            public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
                Integer i1 = list.indexOf(s1);
                Integer i2 = list.indexOf(s2);
                // return i1.compareTo(i2);
                return i2.compareTo(i1);
            }
        });
    }
}
```